# Done/close button on PhoneGap's InAppBrowser not showing

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm trying to show the done/close button on the inAppBrowser instance inside PhoneGap.

The code I'm using to call the url: `window.open(encodeURI(url), '_blank', 'location=yes');`

In my config.xml: `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />`

I've tried different (older) versions of the `inappbrowser` plugin, but that didn't help. I've been researching this problem and it seems like I'm running the right code, but it's not working. Same issue on both iOS and Android.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to add the "closebuttoncaption" variable

   window.open(encodeURI(url), '_blank', 'location=yes,closebuttoncaption=Close');
2. You simply could debug the inappbrowser page on the remote device 
   https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: I've tried closebuttoncaption=Close, but it didn't help. How's chrome dev tools helpful for debugging a phonegap app? It's be awesome to use that to debug a complied app. Please educate me. :)

Comment: Check the link in the answer. You need an Android 4.4 minimum for remove debugging WebViews.